# send email programmatically without using EMAIL ID configured in Blackberry device?

Tags: email, blackberry

I am developing a Social Application in which I need to **send email** as a request to other users as an Application Invitation.  However, my requirement is that I don't want to use the E-mail ID configured in the device.

I want to send the Email from the **support ID** of my firm. I do not want to use the USER'S Email ID.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

I very much doubt that would be possible from the device. If it were then any application could spoof mail from any email address. This would not be a good thing.

Your application could, for example, send the information needed to compose the email to your company server which would then send the mail out.

Another option would be to integrate your application with BlackBerry Messenger. Invitation to download your application would then take very little effort on your part and not require use of your company servers at all.

Comment: that means I can not send mails from my(programmer) decided email Id, and not from the User's email ID...but I have done this in Android.

Comment: Is it actually sent from an email id that you decide, or are you simply inserting a From or Reply-To header. There is a big difference.

Comment: I want to configure the EMAIL address of my firm and that will be the FROM address always to send the support mails....!!!

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on what you want to do.  An easy way to send emails in a BlackBerry app is to [do something like this](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11935/Create_new_populated_email_msg_565427_11.jsp):

```java
Message m = new Message();
Address a = new Address("mLi@rim.com", "Ming Li");
Address[] addresses = {a};
m.addRecipients(net.rim.blackberry.api.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO, addresses);
m.setContent("A message for you...");
m.setSubject("Email for you");
Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_MESSAGES, new MessageArguments(m));
```

If that's what you want to do, then you'll see [from the API docs](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/invoke/MessageArguments.html) that there is no **FROM** field available in the `MessageArguments` class.  So, invoking the email application will use the device's configured email account, [as Richard suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14242923/119114).

But, unless I don't know something about the BlackBerry network infrastructure (like they have filtering that would stop this), I don't see why you couldn't write your own small email client, to connect to the destination server, and send the message with whatever email headers you like.  A simple J2ME [SMTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol) client might look [like this sample code](http://itminds-usefullinks.blogspot.com/2011/12/sending-mail-from-j2me-app-wihtout-web_01.html).  (**Note:** I haven't tried that code, but at first glance, it looks like the right approach).  Of course, it's certainly more code than the snippet I posted above!

One of the big problems with much of our existing email infrastructure is that the sender's address isn't *authenticated*.  So you can say that [the email is from whoever you want](http://www.arclab.com/products/amlc/how-to-read-and-analyze-the-email-header-fields-spf-dkim.html).  This is one reason why spam and [phishing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phishing) are such big problems.  Anyone who wants to can send you an email that claims to be from your bank, or someone else that they're not.

Now, I don't write spam filters, and every destination mail server can be using a different algorithm.  It's possible that your users will find their spam filters trapping your emails, depending on what **FROM** address you use, and how you route the message to their SMTP server (which BlackBerry transport you use).

So, this might not work *well* for you.  Anyway, I just wanted to show how it *could* be done in a J2ME app ... you may need to post part of this question on a true IT forum, and see what people have to say about the **spam filter** issue.

[Here's a discussion on the topic](http://forums.xkcd.com/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=67482)